# How can I make my PC stop changing the COM when inserting a new USB cable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I am not sure if this question is right for this forum, but I'll try.

I have five different USB cables. I need a null modem for them to work efficiently, which I at this moment only can use on one port at the time (so the port changing is an issue.)

Is there any way to stop the computer from adding a new COM and instead to always use the same COM port for that specific physical port in my computer?

For instance, I plug cable 1 into my computer, I get COM3 in the device manager. I plug in the same type of cable called cable 2, which automatically gets COM 5, etc. Each time I plug a new cable into the same physical USB port I get different COMs in my device manager. Is there any way to stop this from happening on my PC? Running Windows 10.

I don't want to have to go into the device manager and un-install the driver all the time. I also don't want to have to re-install the null modem every time the COM port number changes. There must be some efficient way to do this.

Comment: (1) This might help: How to Clean Up or Reset COM Port Numbers in Windows? - Windows OSHub, 2022jan30
http://woshub.com/how-to-clean-up-and-reset-com-ports-in-windows-7/. (2) This is a FAQ for both PC Windows and Linux. ***There are ways to keep the COM port number not changing***, but the ricks are a bit complicated, and not at all newbie friendly. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: Windows does not care about the usb port used. Com port numbers for USB adapters are assigned based on USB pid/vid/serial so should be consistent that cable A gets com port N while Cable B gets com port N+1 etc. Unless they share the pid/vid/serial then it's a free-for-all. Try superuser maybe they can provide a better answer but I doubt it. Maybe you can script  it to clear out all reserved com ports and reassign whatever is plugged in to the com port you want. But that's going to take some hacking and time to write.